# Is an FD(functional dependency) fully fd when x->y and z->y where z is not a subset of x?

Tags: rdbms, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

I have seen many examples about fully functional dependencies, but they use to say that:

x->y such that y shouldn't be determined by any proper subset of x, x has to be a key.

But, what if y is determined by an attribute other than the proper subset or subset of x.

Suppose that I have a **students** table which consists of rollno(primary key), name, phone no unique not null, email unique not null.

As rollno is a primary key, let it be x and take name as y.

now x->y, but phone or email also determine y(name) which are not subsets of x. Is this still called a fully functional dependent?

If yes, should we check the determinants of y which are only subsets of x?

If no, what is the mistake I did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> x->y such that y shouldn't be determined by any proper subset of x, x has to be a key.

You are confusing the definition of "full functional dependency" with the definition of "2NF". The definition of fully functionally dependent has nothing to do with superkeys or candidate keys or primary keys. And for a relation to be in 2NF, *if* X is a candidate key *and* Y is *non-prime* then Y can't be determined by any proper subset of X.

A functional dependency X -> Y is partial when Y is also functionally dependent on a proper/smaller subset of X. Otherwise it is full. It doesn't matter what else is true.

A superkey is a column or set of columns that functionally determines every column. If there is no smaller superkey inside it then it is a candidate key. A relation is in 2NF when every attribute is fully functionally dependent on every candidate key. It doesn't matter what else is true.

You can pick one candidate key to call primary key. So a primary key is a candidate key. Otherwise the notion of "primary key" is irrelevant to functional dependencies and normalization.

(In SQL `primary key` means the same as `unique not null`, namely *superkey*. Which is a candidate key only if there's no smaller superkey in it. So a set *declared* `primary key` might not even *be* a primary key. And in SQL you can't declare {} as a superkey.)

> As rollno is a primary key, let it be x and take name as y.

A primary key is a candidate key, so {`rollno`} determines every attribute and no proper subset of {`rollno`} determines every attribute. So {}, the only proper subset of {`rollno`}, is not a superkey. ({} is a superkey when there can only ever be at most one row in the table.) But it's still possible that {} -> `name`. (That would be if the `name` column only contains at most one name at a time.) Then {`rollno`} -> `name` would be partial because its proper subset {} determines `name`.

> now x->y, but phone or email also determine y(name) which are not subsets of x. Is this still called a fully functional dependent?

If no proper subset of {`rollno`} determines `name` then {`rollno`} -> `name` fully, otherwise partially. That's what the definition says. Nothing else matters. But we *don't know* whether proper subset of {`rollno`} determines `name` because you didn't say whether {} -> `name`.

If {`rollno`}, {`phoneno`} and {`email`} are candidate keys and {} doesn't determine `name` then `name` is fully functionally dependent on all three (because no proper subset of any of them determines `name`).

Comment: Is my table also in 3NF?
I think it has transitive relationship.
rollno->phoneno
phone->name
i.e., rollno->name
But rollno alone can determine name without phoneno. So, is the above set of dependencies mean transitive relation?

Comment: Please post a new question. But note the definition of transitive dependence: X -> Z transitively when there is some Y where X -> Y and Y -> Z *and* not (Y -> X).

Answer (score 0):

You are saying:

> x->y such that y shouldn't be determined by any proper subset of x, x has to be a key.

but this mixes two different concepts, that of “full functional dependency”, and that of “key”.

A functional dependency is *full* if you cannot remove any element of the left part without losing the propoerty of determining the right part. So if a functional dependency has *only* one attribute on the left part (like `rollno → name`), it is *always* complete.

A (candidate) key on the other hand is a set of attributes that determines all the attributes of a relation, and such that you cannot remove any attribute from it without losing the property of being a key (so, it is not a superkey).

In your example there are three different keys, `rollno`, `phone`, and `email`, each of them composed by a single attribute.

Of course, if you know that the set of attributes `X` is a key, you can write that `X → T`, where `T` are all the attributes of the relation, and *this* functional dependency is complete.

Comment: According to 2NF, it says that any non-prime attribute should be fully functional dependent on prime attributes. So, as per your explaination about fully functional dependency, I think my relation is fully functional dependent as there is only 1 prime attribute. Am I correct?

Comment: Any non-prime attribute should be fully functional dependent from a key (not a prime attribute, which could be only part of a key). Your relation is in 2NF since the only non-prime attribute (name) depends from a single attribute. More, (and more important), your relation is alson in BCNF and 3NF.

Comment: @AvinashReddyPaduri "my relation is fully functional dependent" doesn't make sense. It's *(sets of) attributes* that are or are not fully functionally dependent (on (sets of) attributes). A *relation* either does or does not satisfy 2NF.

Comment: @AvinashReddyPaduri "According to 2NF, it says that any non-prime attribute should be fully functional dependent on prime attributes" No, it doesnt. It says that any non-prime attribute should be fully functionally dependent on every candidate key. A CK is a *set* of attributes, and there can be more than one CK.

Comment: @Renzo 1. Each CK is a superkey. Maybe you are trying to say that "CK" & "superkey" are different concepts. 2. {} can be a superkey. 3. If a relation is not in 2NF then it has a set of attributes that is a CK yet partially determines some attribute(s).